# Broadleaf APIs not working

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I'm trying to consume Broadleaf APIs to Create Cart, Add Item and Checkout on a consumer application. 
Cloned Demo application and modified the configuration as per the link:
https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/rest/rest-tutorials

Problems:
1. Create new Cart-> 
POST: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/cart
Exception: HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
With GET request: worked

2. Add Product ID:
   POST: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/cart/1?categoryId=1&customerId=100
   Exception:HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
   GET Request worked but the product is not added.

3.Add a Payment to the Order
POST: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/cart/checkout/payment?customerId=100
Added the OrderPaymentWrapper in the body as mentioned in the above URL
Exception:
messageKey": "queryParameterNotPresent",
            "message": "com.broadleafcommerce.rest.api.exception.BroadleafWebServicesException.queryParameterNotPresent"

Alternatively, referred https://demo.broadleafcommerce.org/api/v2/swagger-ui.html#/ to invoke the API as per the swagger documentation.
Same issue, unable to create a order flow.

I've tried to debug by running on localhost https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite
Same issue.

Please advise.

Comment: What version of Broadleaf are you using? The 5.2 APIs (our latest) listen on port 8082 and 8445, but if you are using 8080 it appears you are not using the latest version. The right answer depends on what version you are using.

Comment: Thanks @phillipuniverse. Yes, i've cloned the latest Broadleaf spring boot application and ran the API module. Referred localhost:8082/api/v1/swagger-ui.html (same issue as i stated above such as creating cart says POST request is not supported). Unable to create order using APIs.  Please suggest if i'm missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an outstanding issue with our `@FrameworkController` annotation. I opened an issue in Broadleaf at https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/Issues/issues/3 with more information as to why it is currently failing.

The workaround is to modify `CustomCartEndpoint` in the API project that you have to add in the `createNewCartForCustomer()` method. The final implementation of `CustomCartEndpoint` should look like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart",
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public class CustomCartEndpoint extends CartEndpoint {

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public OrderWrapper findCartForCustomer(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            return super.findCartForCustomer(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // if we failed to find the cart, create a new one
            return createNewCartForCustomer(request);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public OrderWrapper createNewCartForCustomer(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return super.createNewCartForCustomer(request);
    }
}
```